# Who funded Charles Xavier's school?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe

I know that Xavier was rich, very rich:

1. He ran his own school for years
2. He built Cerebro
3. He owned an exotic aircraft (possibly worth hundreds of millions of dollars)
4. He rebuilt the mansion, including the contents (even if the X-Men supplied the labor)
5. He (probably?) was held responsible for the damage his team did to the city

How could he afford it? Was there any other person or organization also funding his activities?

Comment: I read the title as *founded* and was about to reply, *Well, Charles Xavier, duh!*

Comment: The ability to read anyone's mind around the world really leads to some amazing money making opportunities.  Even basic insider trading, or even subtly suggesting things.  Xavier could send his consciousness back in time? Maybe he suggested the making of google?

Comment: @TrevorD He could, right. But personally I don't think he was that kind of people to do so.

Comment: He used his telepathic abilities to rob banks. People didn't know about the robberies because he telepathicly deleted those memories from everyone's mind using Cerebro. _Duh!_

Comment: *duh!* thing is going too far I think.. ***duh!*** , anyways, Xavier already was very rich, and probably he has some profitable businesses using them and probably he has got some investors, donors and paying students who was sent by their rich parents (Ex: As I remember, Angel from X-3)

Answer (score 12):

Xavier has a family inherited mansion, is a natural genius and attended Oxford University. It seems he inherited a lot of money from his father.

Even in *X-Men: First Class* a CIA agent was involved in their mission and Cerebro was made by Hank not Xavier.

And he is running a school, so maybe some of his students pay. In the comics he had rich students too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking there was a lot of tuition money coming in from parents that really loved their kids but didn't want the world to know they were parents of a mutant.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths we don't know background of all the children. And in comics we did had rich kids like Angel, Wolverine also had some stack of money but in film we are not fully sure.